# looking for pattern to print numbers inside a specific range

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a way to print the numbers `in a range (1100,1148)` in the below output :

> 1100 1104(+4 from the previous) 1109(+5 from the previous) 1113(+4
>   from the previous) 1117(+4 from the previous) 1122(+5 from the
>   previous) 1126(+4 from the previous) 1130(+4 from the previous)
>   1135(+5 from the previous) 1139(+4 from the previous) 1143(+4 from the
>   previous) 1148(+5 from the previous)

I have tried to use a for loop and a counter (to check the + 5 mode) but doesn't seem to work out.

```
text_file = open(r"C:\DOUBLE\cron_file.txt","w")
count = 0
for i in range(1100,1148):
    if count != 3:
        text_file.write(" elndchtNI %d\n" %i)
        i+4
        count+1
    else:
        i+5
        text_file.write("elndchtNI %d \n" %i)

text_file.close()
```

So i want the below output

> elndchtNI 1100 elndchtNI 1104 elndchtNI 1109 elndchtNI 1113 elndchtNI
>   1117 elndchtNI 1122 elndchtNI 1126 elndchtNI 1130 elndchtNI 1135
>   elndchtNI 1139 elndchtNI 1143 elndchtNI 1148

but i get the below :

> elndchtNI 1048 elndchtNI 1049 elndchtNI 1050 elndchtNI 1051 elndchtNI
>   1052 elndchtNI 1053 elndchtNI 1054 elndchtNI 1055 elndchtNI 1056
>   elndchtNI 1057 elndchtNI 1058 elndchtNI 1059 elndchtNI 1060 elndchtNI
>   1061 elndchtNI 1062 elndchtNI 1063 elndchtNI 1064 elndchtNI 1065
>   elndchtNI 1066 elndchtNI 1067 elndchtNI 1068 elndchtNI 1069 elndchtNI
>   1070 elndchtNI 1071 elndchtNI 1072 elndchtNI 1073 elndchtNI 1074
>   elndchtNI 1075 elndchtNI 1076 elndchtNI 1077 elndchtNI 1078 elndchtNI
>   1079 elndchtNI 1080 elndchtNI 1081 elndchtNI 1082 elndchtNI 1083
>   elndchtNI 1084 elndchtNI 1085 elndchtNI 1086 elndchtNI 1087 elndchtNI
>   1088 elndchtNI 1089 elndchtNI 1090 elndchtNI 1091 elndchtNI 1092
>   elndchtNI 1093 elndchtNI 1094 elndchtNI 1095

Comment: I am having a really hard time trying to understand what output you're expecting. Just to double-check, you want to count up from `1100` with increments of `4` but every third interation, you want to increment the counter by `5`? Did I understand what you're trying to accomplish correct?

Comment: You are missing  an = `count+=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
def generator(a, b):
    count=1
    number = a
    while number <= b:
        yield number
        if count<= 1:
            number+=4
            count+=1
        else:
            number+=5
            count=0

text_file = open(r"cron_file.txt","w")
res = ''
for i in generator(1100, 1148):
    res += 'elndchtNI ' + str(i) + ' '
text_file.write(res)
text_file.close()
```

Hello, here is a solution with a generator that return:

```
elndchtNI 1100 elndchtNI 1104 elndchtNI 1109 elndchtNI 1113 elndchtNI 1117 elndchtNI 1122 elndchtNI 1126 elndchtNI 1130 elndchtNI 1135 elndchtNI 1139 elndchtNI 1143 elndchtNI 1148
```

Comment: You would need to initialise res to an empty string to make example work,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not writing the output to a file here - just providing an alternate solution:
You were not incrementing counters properly in your example.
This is a closer approximation to your original code.

```
count = 0
oc = 0
offset = [4,5,4]
for i in range(1100,1149):
    if count == 0:
        print(i)
    elif offset[oc] == count:
        print(i)
        oc +=1
        oc %=3
        count = 0
    count +=1
```

This yields:

```
1100
1104
1109
1113
1117
1122
1126
1130
1135
1139
1143
1148
```

And BTW the Python range needs to be 1 more than 1148 if you want that last output.